# Best way to get inner text of an element target

Tags: javascript

I'm invoking the method both on `keypress` and `click`. Is there a shorter way of getting the letter that's been clicked or a shorter way of testing if a letter's been pressed on the keyboard on line 5?

```
function compareLetters(e) {
  let isMatch = false;
  const letterSelected = e.type === 'click' ? e.target.innerText : String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

  if (!/[a-z]/.test(letterSelected)) return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a letter's been pressed, you might try this ...

```
function compareLetters(e) {
   if ( e.keyCode ) {
      if (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) {
         // this matches a-z
         return;
      }
   } else {
      // process for click
   }
}
```